# Image.Source from Bitmap not being showed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image

I have a Bitmap list where I store some images. Then I want an `Image` element on a WPF `UserControl` to be the first element of that list. For that I tried this:

```
Image2.Source = myBitmapArray[0].ToBitmapImage();
```

Where `ToBitmapImage` is a static function that looks like this:

```
public static BitmapImage ToBitmapImage(this Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = memoryStream;
            bitmapImage.EndInit();
        }

        return bitmapImage;
    }
```

But when I assign the `BitmapImage` to my `Image.Source` it doesn't show the image. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are disposing the `MemoryStream` after assigning it to the `StreamSource` property.

But accoding to [`BitmapImage.StreamSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource(v=vs.110).aspx) you have to

> set the CacheOption property to BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad if you wish to close the stream after the BitmapImage is created. The default OnDemand cache option retains access to the stream until the bitmap is needed, and cleanup is handled by the garbage collector.

So either drop the `using` statement so the `MemoryStream` won't be disposed or use the `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`.

Comment: Great! What a mistake... It works now. Thanks! (7 min to accept your answer)